# Probability that hitting is a good idea in blackjack

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

If I know exactly what cards are left in the deck, what the dealer's current hand is, and what my current hand is, how would I go about calculating the probability that hitting is a good idea. So, it would be beneficial to hit if the probability that you will win after drawing a random card is greater than the probability that you will win with your current hand. Furthermore, the probability that you will win is the probability that your hand is higher than what the dealer's hand will be when he finishes drawing (I'm assuming they stop on 17 or higher) OR the dealer busts. I'm struggling mainly to pin down the exact probability that your hand will be higher than the dealers. Say the count of your hand is $X$, then the probability of you losing would be the probability of the dealer drawing any hand between 17 and 21 (inclusive) that is also greater than $X$. I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around figuring out how to calculate this, and any help would be hugely appreciated. Also, I know this question is a bit long, so if there are any clarifications I can provide, please let me know.

Comment: I don't see any "short" way of doing it.  You would use a picking-without-replacement probabilistic argument to consider what the "next" sum is likely to be.

Comment: Any way you'd care to elaborate a bit? Specifically, I'm having trouble figuring out the probability of the dealer beating me, given that I have a particular hand. So say the dealer has an 8 face up, and my hand is a 17. How would I figure out the odds of the dealer beating me?

Comment: I think the answer below elaborates along the lines of what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you can compute the chance that you win if you stand.  To compute the chance you win if you draw, you compute the chance that you draw an ace, then the chance you win assuming you draw an ace.  Multiply them and you have one part of the chance you win if you draw. Then compute the chance you draw a two and the chance you win assuming you draw a two and so on.  Add up all the chances and compare it with the chance you win if you stand.

As an extremely simple example (you will never know this many cards) suppose you have $17$, the dealer shows $6$ and the unknown cards are $2, 2, 10, 10$. If you stand, it is $50\%$ that the dealer has $10$ and must draw.  It is then $\frac 13$ he draws another $10$ and busts.  In all other cases you lose, so you will win $\frac 16$ by standing.  If you draw, you bust $50\%$ and get $19 \ 50\%$.  If you get $19$ you win, so you win $\frac 12$ of the time.  Clearly you should draw.

Comment: Sure, I'd gotten to this part about, I'm mainly struggling to figure out how I'd calculate the probability of winning, given that I choose to stay on a specific hand. This is the probability of the dealer either busting, or drawing to something between 17 and less than my hand. I'm also not sure, in this scenario would I just straight up ADD the probability of them busting to whatever I calculate as the probability of them drawing lower than me?

Comment: Standing is the easier one to compute because you don't have the variable of your draw. Yes, you add the two probabilities because they are disjoint.  If the dealer draws to 17 and below your hand he stops, doesn't bust, and you win.  If he busts he stops and you win.  In all other cases you tie or lose.

Comment: OK, so if I can figure out how to compute standing, then I can just to a sum over all possible cards I could draw, and compute standing with the result. Awesome. Would you have any advice at all on how to go about computing the probability of the dealer getting lower than me? Say I choose to stand on a 19, and the dealer has a 5 turned over, I'd like to figure out a way to compute the probability of the dealer drawing lower than me, i.e. drawing to a 17 or an 18. I'm struggling to figure out how to go about computing this though. Thank you for all your help by the way!

Comment: You just look at how many cards are left in the deck that are the right size.  As in my example, that depends on the hole card.  If he shows a 5, there is some chance, which you can compute from the deck that is left, he has a 10 in the hole.  Given that, he needs to draw 2 or 3 to stand and lose to you.  You compute that probability again from the remaining deck.  He might have a 9 in the hole, in which case he needs a 3 or 4 to stand and lose.  If he draws A or 2 he will draw again and you need to assess those probabilities.  I didn't say it was easy-there are many possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Blackjack is a solvable game and I solved it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985886/can-anyone-confirm-expectations-for-the-game-of-blackjack?noredirect=1#comment6161797_2985886)! Using Mathematica and symbolic computation. If you want to get more into this I can tell you how to do it.